# How to make a query page template on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table.

I want to create a a new tab with a textbox on it.

The user can enter a keyword into the textbox.

It should return all rows where one of the fields contains the keyword.

How would I implement this?

My databases are:
CNPJ, NOME, OPTION TICKER, DATA

Comment: What are the *specific* problems you're having with doing this? What have you tried already, and what exactly prevented you from completing it?  Please review [ask] and consider editing your question to add more details.  There are plenty of helpful posts to be found via googling (eg) "Excel search form".  Like this one: https://www.exceltip.com/excel-macros-and-vba/search-and-print-through-vba.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out an example in VBA(Excel) that might help you with your problem:

First you need a tab with all the data in it. This tab is named "myData".

Here's how it will look:

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNbG8.jpg)

Secondly, you will require a VBA module with the following code and a Results tab:

```
Public myDataArray() As Variant
Public mySearchWord As String
Public resultsArray() As Variant

Sub my_search_engine()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Cells.ClearContents

Dim numberOfRecords As Double
numberOfRecords = 1
numberOfResultRecords = 1

mySearchWord = InputBox("Type your search word", "Search box", "Type here")
Sheets("myData").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
myDataArray = Selection

For i = LBound(myDataArray) To UBound(myDataArray)

        If mySearchWord = myDataArray(i, 1) Or mySearchWord = myDataArray(i, 2) Or mySearchWord = myDataArray(i, 3) Or mySearchWord = myDataArray(i, 4) Then
                        
                ReDim Preserve resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 1) = myDataArray(i, 1)
                ReDim Preserve resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 2) = myDataArray(i, 2)
                ReDim Preserve resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 3) = myDataArray(i, 3)
                ReDim Preserve resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4) = myDataArray(i, 4)
        
                Sheets("Results").Cells(numberOfResultRecords, 1) = resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 1)
                Sheets("Results").Cells(numberOfResultRecords, 2) = resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 2)
                Sheets("Results").Cells(numberOfResultRecords, 3) = resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 3)
                Sheets("Results").Cells(numberOfResultRecords, 4) = resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                
                ReDim resultsArray(numberOfRecords, 4)
                
                numberOfResultRecords = numberOfResultRecords + 1
                
        Else: End If
        
Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, the code stores your initial data in a VBA array and loops through each record of the data looking for matches based on the input you give. As soon as the code gets a match, it will put it in the results tab.

For instance: If you look for the word: "A1" (See image below)

[Search word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t70lC.jpg)

The code will return all the records where "A1" is.

Here is the output:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PqaC.jpg)

I hope this help and if it does please mark my answer as correct. Cheers!